# Getting error with viewbag list

Tags: string, list, int, viewbag

Hi guys I am trying to convert a List to List and pass with Viewbag, but it just showing the last number.

For example:

```
string strIDs = "15,20,30,44";
List<int> IDs = strIDs.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();

            foreach (int myNumbers in IDs)
            {
                ViewBag.Numeros = myNumbers ;
            }
```

View:

```
@ViewBag.Numeros
```

Which the result is just showing the number 44. So If you guys can help me please, thanks Fernando.

Comment: That's because you are iterating through the list of `IDs` and setting `ViewBag.Numeros` to `15`, then `20`, then `30`, then finally `44`.

Comment: Hi, I could not understand, Is it possible to provide an example? Thanks Fernando.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:

```
string strIDs = "15,20,30,44";
List<int> IDs = strIDs.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
ViewBag.Numeros = IDs ;
```

And then the view:

```
@if (@ViewBag.Numeros != null)
{
    foreach (int mybag in @ViewBag.Numeros) { 
    @mybag
      }

}
```

Thanks all :/)